# I want to get any struct field value , how can I do that?

Tags: go

An API returns weather data like this：

```
{
  "HeWeather6": [
    {
      "basic": {
        "cid": "CN101010100",
        "location": "北京",
        "parent_city": "北京",
        "admin_area": "北京",
        "cnty": "中国",
        "lat": "39.90498734",
        "lon": "116.4052887",
        "tz": "+8.00"
      },
      "update": {
        "loc": "2019-11-17 20:09",
        "utc": "2019-11-17 12:09"
      },
      "status": "ok",
      "now": {
        "cloud": "91",
        "cond_code": "101",
        "cond_txt": "多云",
        "fl": "-5",
        "hum": "12",
        "pcpn": "0.0",
        "pres": "1024",
        "tmp": "4",
        "vis": "8",
        "wind_deg": "300",
        "wind_dir": "西北风",
        "wind_sc": "5",
        "wind_spd": "38"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I created types such as

```
// Root - 123
type Root struct {
    HEWEATHER6 HeWeather `json:"HeWeather6"`
}

// HeWeather - 123
type HeWeather []struct {
    BASIC  Basic  `json:"basic"`
    UPDATE Update `json:"update"`
    NOW    Now    `json:"now"`
}

// Basic - 123
type Basic struct {
    Cid        string `json:"cid"`
    Location   string `json:"location"`
    ParentCity string `json:"parent_city"`
    AdminArea  string `json:"admin_area"`
    Cnty       string `json:"cnty"`
    Lat        string `json:"lat"`
    Lon        string `json:"lon"`
    Tz         string `json:"tz"`
}

// Update - 123
type Update struct {
    Loc string `json:"loc"`
    Utc string `json:"utc"`
}

// Now - 123
type Now struct {
    Cloud    string `json:"cloud"`
    CondCode string `json:"cond_code"`
    CondTxt  string `json:"cond_txt"`
    Fl       string `json:"fl"`
    Hum      string `json:"hum"`
    Pcpn     string `json:"pcpn"`
    Pres     string `json:"pres"`
    Tmp      string `json:"tmp"`
    Vis      string `json:"vis"`
    WindDeg  string `json:"wind_deg"`
    WindDir  string `json:"wind_dir"`
    WindSc   string `json:"wind_sc"`
    WindSpd  string `json:"wind_spd"`
}
```

How do I store, for example, a single location data into a variable and print it on stdout?

Comment: So, you get a json file as API response which contains data of your `Root` structure?

Comment: I also think the json is not valid, its missing some opening and closing `{}` 
I have corrected the JSON if the json is correct then you should be able to unmarshall the json into the struct and get the required value 
https://play.golang.org/p/ysCZCin5kjU

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) to unmarshal your json into your structure, and access your value with the dot notation syntax.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

// Root - 123
type Root struct {
    HEWEATHER6 HeWeather `json:"HeWeather6"`
}

// HeWeather - 123
type HeWeather []struct {
    BASIC  Basic  `json:"basic"`
    UPDATE Update `json:"update"`
    NOW    Now    `json:"now"`
}

// Basic - 123
type Basic struct {
    Cid        string `json:"cid"`
    Location   string `json:"location"`
    ParentCity string `json:"parent_city"`
    AdminArea  string `json:"admin_area"`
    Cnty       string `json:"cnty"`
    Lat        string `json:"lat"`
    Lon        string `json:"lon"`
    Tz         string `json:"tz"`
}

// Update - 123
type Update struct {
    Loc string `json:"loc"`
    Utc string `json:"utc"`
}

// Now - 123
type Now struct {
    Cloud    string `json:"cloud"`
    CondCode string `json:"cond_code"`
    CondTxt  string `json:"cond_txt"`
    Fl       string `json:"fl"`
    Hum      string `json:"hum"`
    Pcpn     string `json:"pcpn"`
    Pres     string `json:"pres"`
    Tmp      string `json:"tmp"`
    Vis      string `json:"vis"`
    WindDeg  string `json:"wind_deg"`
    WindDir  string `json:"wind_dir"`
    WindSc   string `json:"wind_sc"`
    WindSpd  string `json:"wind_spd"`
}

func main() {
    b := `{
  "HeWeather6": [
    {
      "basic": {
        "cid": "CN101010100",
        "location": "北京",
        "parent_city": "北京",
        "admin_area": "北京",
        "cnty": "中国",
        "lat": "39.90498734",
        "lon": "116.4052887",
        "tz": "+8.00"
      },
      "update": {
        "loc": "2019-11-17 20:09",
        "utc": "2019-11-17 12:09"
      },
      "status": "ok",
      "now": {
        "cloud": "91",
        "cond_code": "101",
        "cond_txt": "多云",
        "fl": "-5",
        "hum": "12",
        "pcpn": "0.0",
        "pres": "1024",
        "tmp": "4",
        "vis": "8",
        "wind_deg": "300",
        "wind_dir": "西北风",
        "wind_sc": "5",
        "wind_spd": "38"
      }
    }
  ]
}`

    t := &Root{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(t.HEWEATHER6[0].BASIC.Location)

}
```

Working example here : https://play.golang.org/p/6iGVQeZU1_Z

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the same structure to parse the JSON response.

```golang
data := &Root{}
json.Unmarshal([]byte(JsonString), data)
```

2. Then you can access any sub-fields of the `Root` structure.

```golang
// like HeWeather structure 
heWeather := data.HEWEATHER6
```